# Attempting to get Email to work in Laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

Well let me first start out by saying I'm pretty new to laravel 5.  I've been searching forever on google trying to get just a simple email to send just by typing in the appropriate URL with no luck.  Unfortunately, the documentation out there I have found wasn't that helpful,  and just gives a broad look(I understand laravel 5 is new, but still frustrating haha).   There is nothing fancy about what I'm trying to do, I just want to get that too work before I do anything else.  I'm trying to get this to work with just using gmail as of right now, but once I get that down I will of course, try something like Mailgun.  This is the code I have as of right now The first one is in mail.php:

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => env('smtp'),



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => ['address' =>"exmaple@gmail.com" , 'name' => "example_name"],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('example@gmail.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => env('example'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

];
```

This is in my routes:

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
Mail::send('Email.test', function ($message)
{
    $message->to('example@gmail.com', 'example_name')->subject('Welcome!');
});
});
```

I also tried the `MailController@Sending_Email` for the path as well.
This is in my MailController:

```
class MailController extends Controller{
public function Sending_Email()
{
   $this->call('GET','Email.test');
    return View('Email.test');
}

}
```

and my view is this simple code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>hey this is a test to see if my email system works</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my error:
`Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), called in         /vagrant/leonis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on     line 89 and defined`

Comment: I would love to say that worked, but unfortunately It didn't.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: no I'm getting this one now

Comment: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given, called in /vagrant/leonis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 213 and defined

Comment: Did you see my answer below? I walked through what I believe your multiple issues are, hopefully you'll be sending mail once you go through that.

Comment: you can try this process for laravel 5.1 
this worked for me
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31193005/2503722

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple issues going on. First off:

```
'driver' => env('smtp'),
```

The `env` method looks to your .env file. My guess is you don't have a "smtp" entry in your .env file. I would simply change it to this:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
```

That should take care of the `createDriver()` error.

If you still have issues with the driver, or later on have issues authenticating to your SMTP server, do a quick check of your config at runtime:

```
dd(Config::get("mail"));
```

Since you have `env()` checking for .env settings and then falling back to default values, it can be helpful to see what the generated config looks like.

Now you still have an issue with how you are calling `Mail::send`. This is your code:

```
Mail::send('Email.test', function ($message)
```

And this is from the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#basic-usage):

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
```

Notice that the second argument is an array. The callback function should be the *third* argument.

From the docs:

> The second is the data to be passed to the view, often as an associative array where the data items are available to the view by $key.

So do something like this:

```
Mail::send('Email.test', [], function ($message) { 
    $message->to('example@gmail.com', 'example_name')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Comment: ok cool thanks, alright i fixed it there.  I never knew you had to change the .env file to appropriate information, .  'Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)'  Yeah i saw that, and tried it that way before as well as again.  To be honest I don't know exactly what that is doing.  I'm just trying to get the email to display the view.  what is the key and the value suppose to represent?

Comment: And your absolutely right that it has to be that because this is the error i'm getting now.   Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given, called in /vagrant/leonis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 213 and defined    On a side note thank you so much for taking the time to help, I've been stuck trying to get this work for awhile now haha

Comment: The key/value is data that you may want to pass to the view file. Often in an email you may have things like "Hello {{customer}} here is your receipt." So in the array you might have `["customer" => "John Doe"]` so that it is populated in the email. Feel free to make it just an empty `[]` for now if you aren't using that.

Comment: ok, crap then lol.  it must be something else, because i did try [] and I'm still getting that error i sent before.  It looks like this               Route::get('test', function()
{
    Mail::send('Email.test', function ($message)
    {
        $message->to('example@gmail.com',  [], 'example')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
});

Comment: Show your updated code. If you put an empty array in for the second argument, you can't possibly be getting the same `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given` error.

Comment: ErrorException in Mailer.php line 148:
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given, called in /vagrant/leonis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 213 and defined

Comment: `Route::get('test', function()
{
    Mail::send('Email.test', function ($message)
    {
        $message->to('example@gmail.com',  [], 'example')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
});`

Comment: The array should be the _second_ argument of the _send()_ method. Look at Laravel's example again. It doesn't go in the _to()_ method.

Comment: wow I'm idiot, thank you. I still have issues but that fixed that part thanks

Comment: yeah np, very new to this site, where on the page is that?

Answer (score 4):

You may need to

```
php artisan config:clear
```

then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Just `php artisan config:clear` was enough to store me.