# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed

Tags: php

**Hi Everyone... i am a beginner in php .... i get that error after composer install**

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed in C:\wamp\www\core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php on line 88 and exactly 1 expected

```
protected function createDriver($driver)
{
    // We'll check to see if a creator method exists for the given driver. If not we
    // will check for a custom driver creator, which allows developers to create
    // drivers using their own customized driver creator Closure to create it.
    if (isset($this->customCreators[$driver])) {
        return $this->callCustomCreator($driver);
    } else {
        $method = 'create'.Str::studly($driver).'Driver';

        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->$method();
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Driver [$driver] not supported.");
}
```

**What sould I Do?**

Comment: show us where createDriver is called ; it looks like the `$driver` is undefined. Are you missing some kind of config parameter somewhere ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083520/attempting-to-get-email-to-work-in-laravel-5 May of be some help. Having the full error trace would help